# how to resolve issue with an unsupported format string passed to builtin_function_or_method.__format__

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do a standardization (z-score normalization)

```
x = data[['BALANCE', 'BALANCE_FREQUENCY', 'PURCHASES']]

std_scale = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(x)
df_std = std_scale.transform(x)

print('Mean after standardization:\nBALANCE={:.2f}, BALANCE_FREQUENCY={:.2f}, PURCHASES={:.2f}'.format(df_std[:,0].mean(), df_std[:,1].mean, df_std[:,2].mean()))

print('\nStandard deviation after standardization:\nBALANCE={:.2f}, BALANCE_FREQUENCY={:.2f}, PURCHASES={:.2f}'.format(df_std[:,0].std(), df_std[:,1].std, df_std[:,2].std()))
```

and I got this error:

```
---> 10       .format(df_std[:,0].mean(), df_std[:,1].mean, df_std[:,2].mean()))
    TypeError: unsupported format string passed to builtin_function_or_method.__format__
```

Comment: You're not *calling* the method (`std`/`mean`) in the second case for each example.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parenthesis in your function calls of `mean` and `std`.

```
print('Mean after standardization:\nBALANCE={:.2f}, BALANCE_FREQUENCY={:.2f}, PURCHASES={:.2f}'.format(df_std[:,0].mean(), df_std[:,1].mean(), df_std[:,2].mean()))

print('\nStandard deviation after standardization:\nBALANCE={:.2f}, BALANCE_FREQUENCY={:.2f}, PURCHASES={:.2f}'.format(df_std[:,0].std(), df_std[:,1].std(), df_std[:,2].std()))
```